# Создать метод в конструкторе?

Tags: javascript

1. Как можно создать функцию (метод ) в методе конструктор ?

```js
class User {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  sayHi() {
    alert('hello');
  }
  }

  

}

// Использование:
let user = new User("Иван");
user.sayHi();
```

Comment: Ого... а можете придумать реальный пример, где такое может правда пригодится?) Просто, если это каждый раз одна и так же функция, нет смысла пересоздавать его отдельно для каждого объекта. Если разная (переданная через параметр), с тем же успехом можно сделать в прототипе функцию, на ходу обрабатывающую получаемые функции / или параметры.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME приветствую не могу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class A {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    
    this.f = function() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  }
}

const a = new A('name');

a.f();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sayHi = () => {
       alert('hello');
     };
  }
```